# Related to traefik's container call restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, traefik

I am a beginner.
I built a service on **Amazon ECS using traefik**.

https://traefik.io/

I have DNS configured for router53 service.

For example, I set it up like * .test.com.

So i can run it like a.test.com or b.test.com on the web.

But, **I want to limit the calls per month for each Docker container.**

All requests are made through traefik.

So I think traefik can handle it.

What part of traefik can i use?

I would appreciate any information you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so:

Some questions for you:

1. If you limit the number of calls per month, what happens if you have many calls in certain week that reach the set threshold?
2. Is your VoIP service support limiting calls per hour or per day from the same user/source?

A reverse proxy will limit calls for active sessions at a given time, which can help you achieve limiting the number of calls depending on the protocol in use.